# Different results when plotting histogram using DataFrame.plot.hist and Series.plot.hist

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

The data for this question can be downloaded from [University of California Irvine](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00492/Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv.gz).

```
import pandas as pd
i_94 = pd.read_csv('./Downloads/Guided_Project_ Finding_Heavy_Traffic_Indicators_on I-94/Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline # for my Jupyter notebook
i_94.plot.hist(column='traffic_volume', bins=10)
traffic_volume = i_94['traffic_volume']
traffic_volume.plot.hist(bins=10)
```

That's all my code. I assumed that my histograms should be identical since they're both plotting the same column. However, I'm seeing the following

[image]

Why are the two histograms different?

Quickly load the sample data

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00492/Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv.gz'

file = 'Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv.gz'

content = requests.get(url).content
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

i_94 = pd.read_csv(file, compression='gzip')
```

Comment: The `bins` are clearly different

Comment: @rafaelc That makes sense. But since they're both set to have 10 bins. Why would they be different? It's just odd default behavior?

Comment: Yeah, seems like an odd default behavior. Edit: Just intuitively, looking at the graphs, it looks like `df.plot.hist` and `df.series.hist` calculate the bins based on different assumptions. That leads to the blue plot having the last two bars missing (you can only count 8 blue bars), while the orange plot has all 10 bars, but stop earlier around `x=7000`. A good way to start investigating is here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.1/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1351

Comment: The OP uses [`pandas.DataFrmae.plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html) (doesn't work as expected), and [`pandas.Series.plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.hist.html) (works as expected). There is also [`pandas.DataFrame.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) and [`pandas.Series.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.hist.html), which both work as expected.

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6arZn.png) comparing `pandas.DataFrame.plot` and `pandas.Series.plot`. Tested in `matplotlib v.3.7.1` and `pandas v2.0.0`.

Comment: [BUG: DataFrame.plot.hist and Series.plot.hist do not produce the same histogram for the same column #53245](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53245)

Answer (score 2):

Bins are calculated based on the numeric values of all columns. So `column=` should be considered as a "display option" (which histograms I want to display) rather than columns where the bins are computed.

The documentation of [pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html):

> A histogram is a representation of the distribution of data. This function groups the values of all given Series in the DataFrame into bins and draws all bins in one matplotlib.axes.Axes. **This is useful when the DataFrame’s Series are in a similar scale**

It's not really clear/explicit but we should understand that the bins will be unique and computed for all Series.

[Relevant code from Pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1a4832bd49d9f41fbbf705b2941ef4484852252a/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/hist.py#L81-L90):

```
def _calculate_bins(self, data: DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    """Calculate bins given data"""
    nd_values = data.infer_objects(copy=False)._get_numeric_data()
    values = np.ravel(nd_values)
    values = values[~isna(values)]

    hist, bins = np.histogram(
        values, bins=self.bins, range=self.kwds.get("range", None)
    )
    return bins
```

So if you isolate the `traffic_volume` column (Dataframe with single column) then the result is the same as for the Series:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

i_94.plot.hist(column='traffic_volume', bins=10, ax=ax1, title='Full Dataframe')

traffic_volume_df = i_94[['traffic_volume']]
traffic_volume_df.plot.hist(column='traffic_volume', bins=10, ax=ax2, title='Dataframe with single column')

traffic_volume_sr = i_94['traffic_volume']
traffic_volume_sr.plot.hist(bins=10, ax=ax3, title='Unique Series')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

**Update**

Details:

```
from pandas.plotting._matplotlib import HistPlot

hist1 = HistPlot(df)
bins1 = hist1._calculate_bins(df)

hist2 = HistPlot(df[['traffic_volume']])
bins2 = hist2._calculate_bins(df[['traffic_volume']])

hist3 = HistPlot(df['traffic_volume'])
bins3 = hist3._calculate_bins(df['traffic_volume'])

hist4 = HistPlot(df[['traffic_volume', 'rain_1h']])
bins4 = hist4._calculate_bins(df[['traffic_volume', 'rain_1h']])

hist5 = HistPlot(df[['traffic_volume', 'weather_description']])
bins5 = hist4._calculate_bins(df[['traffic_volume', 'weather_description']])
```

Output:

```
>>> bins1
array([   0.  ,  983.13, 1966.26, 2949.39, 3932.52, 4915.65, 5898.78,
       6881.91, 7865.04, 8848.17, 9831.3 ])

>>> bins2
array([   0.,  728., 1456., 2184., 2912., 3640., 4368., 5096., 5824.,
       6552., 7280.])

>>> bins3
array([   0.,  728., 1456., 2184., 2912., 3640., 4368., 5096., 5824.,
       6552., 7280.])

>>> bins4
array([   0.  ,  983.13, 1966.26, 2949.39, 3932.52, 4915.65, 5898.78,
       6881.91, 7865.04, 8848.17, 9831.3 ])

>>> bins5
array([   0.,  728., 1456., 2184., 2912., 3640., 4368., 5096., 5824.,
       6552., 7280.])
```

Comment: I have not the same interpretation. I consider `column=` as a display parameter: which column(s) I want to plot.

Comment: I can see your case for this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256790/different-results-when-plotting-histogram-using-dataframe-plot-hist-and-series-p/76257555?noredirect=1#comment134477951_76257555). I don't personally like that implementation. I guess if they close the bug, then I'll know if it's the "expected" behavior. That's kind of a gotcha. However, I think based on the parameter description, that's not the correct interpretation (e.g. `column str or sequence, optional - If passed, will be used to limit data to a subset of columns.`). That limits `data` to a subset.

Comment: Thank you for this discussion. I updated my answer. I hope you get an answer on the issue. I will follow this :)

Comment: You're welcome. The discussion definitely clarified the issue, and this is a much better answer now. +1